# How to save parquet in S3 from AWS SageMaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I would like to save a Spark DataFrame from AWS SageMaker to S3. In Notebook, I ran

`myDF.write.mode('overwrite').parquet("s3a://my-bucket/dir/dir2/")`

I get

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o326.parquet. :
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem not found    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeInFileFormat(DataSource.scala:394)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:471)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:609)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:217)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:508)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem not found    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)

How should I do it correctly in Notebook? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The SageMaker notebook instance is not running Spark code, and it doesn't have the Hadoop or other Java classes that you are trying to invoke.

You usually have in the Jupyter notebook in SageMaker python libraries such as Pandas, and you can use it to write the parquet file (for example, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html ).

Another option is to connect from the Jupyter notebook to an existing (or new) Spark cluster and execute the command remotely there. See here for documentation on how to set this connection up: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/build-amazon-sagemaker-notebooks-backed-by-spark-in-amazon-emr/